# Match column values with Row values to copy a cell from one worksheet to another

Tags: google-sheets

I have  two worksheets

Worksheet 1

```
Name| A | B | C | D |
 Joe|    
 Doe|
 Moe|
```

Worksheet2

```
 Name|Joe | Moe |Toe|Sue|
   1 |    |     |   |   |
total|15  |22   |6  | 0 |
```

What i would like to be able to do is to check all the "Name" values in the range which exists in Worsheet 1 to see if it exists in WorkSheet 2 Range, and if it does then copy the Totals values into corresponding column in worksheet 1.

So worksheet 1 would look like in the example as:

```
 Name| A | B | C | D |
 Joe|  15|   | 
 Doe|
 Moe|  22
```

I have tried query, Vlookup but I am a newbie to spreadsheet, so any assistance would be gladly apprciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HLOOKUP instead. I would nest it in IFERROR function.

[image]